# How to create an 'edit' / 'cancel edit' box with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where I have multiple values in cells and columns. When the user clicks anywhere on a TD cell I want it to:

1. become a textarea
2. paste the current text into the textarea
3. put a cancel button under it
4. once the cancel button is pressed, I want everything to change back as it was before
5. ability to do it again and again from Point #1

Here is my attempt:

HTML:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;text-align: center;" id="tb">
  <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;width:200px;height:100px;">
      <div class="id1">TEST1</div>
    </td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;width:200px;height:100px;">
      <div class="id2">TEST2</div></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;width:200px;height:100px;">
      <div class="id3">TEST3</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
var t = '';
var prevHtml = '';
var thisElement = '';

$(document).on('click', '#tb td', function()
{       prevHtml = $(this).html();
        thisElement = this;
    if ($(this).attr('data-status') == 'active'){return;};
    $(this).attr('data-status', 'active');
    t = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<div class="row custom-status-main"><div class="col-md-12"><textarea maxlength="2000" rows="3" class="form-control" style="font-size: 12px;width: 80%;resize:vertical;">'+t+'</textarea></div></div><div class="row" style="margin-top:5px;"<div class="col-md-6"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-grey cancel-btn">Cancel</button></div></div>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.cancel-btn', function()
{
    $(thisElement).html(prevHtml);
  $(thisElement).removeAttr('data-custom-status');
});
```

This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vsauhkfk/1/

My attempt is working for Point #4 but then it seems like nothing happens when clicking on the TD. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. You had 1 typo and 1 thing missing in your Cancel function that was causing you problems.

You had:

```
$(thisElement).removeAttr('data-custom-status');
```

It should be:

```
$(thisElement).removeAttr('data-status');
```

You were adding the 'data-status' attribute to the element but never removing it.

Also you need to add the stopPropagation() call in your cancel method. Otherwise your click on the cancel button will run your cancel method but the click event will propagate up the DOM to the TD element again and re-trigger your td click.

Here's the code for your cancel function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cancel-btn', function(e)
{
    $(thisElement).html(prevHtml);
  $(thisElement).removeAttr('data-status');
  e.stopPropagation();

});
```

See the working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vsauhkfk/2/

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! Looks almost perfect. Only 1 issue left. When I'm opening e.g.: 3 textareas and then try to cancel the first one, it doesn't work. I suspect it's because the global variable has been changed. Any cure for that?

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vsauhkfk/4/ I've fixed it so it doesn't rely on global variables. I'm using data attributes to contain the original text.

Comment: And if you need to update the TD with what the user types in to the text area. look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vsauhkfk/6/. Note that I'm html encoding the input for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm! Looks like I've learned something pretty useful today! Cheers for your help Gregg!